# Can I automate SFTP to upload an entire tree?

Tags: sftp

Currently I am using SFTP to transfer .HTML and .JS files to my remote filesystem.

I have to type:

```
sftp root@123.456.78.90
```

And then manually change remote directory to /var/www/html, and upload files individually.

I can simultaneously upload all the files in a directory using *,  but this doesn't appear to work for subdirectories.

Is there any way of copying an entire tree?

Is it possible to make a script that changes to the correct folder and performs the copy?

Comment: Have you tried `scp -r`? You should have no problem if ssh is not restricted, otherwise you can use `lftp` client, it allows you to mirror trees.

Answer (score 1):

Use `put -r`. The sftp client in openssh-clients-6.4 knows the `-r` option, some older clients don't.

You might also want to have a look at the `-p` option (preserve).